# Moving installation files between drives

Tags: hard-drive

I want to move my installation files in Windows 10 (.exe/.msi) files from my downloads folder on C drive to a different disc to free up space.
I do realize they would not play nice if executed from the different drive, but if I needed to use them again could I not simply move them back to C and execute as needed as the file paths and registry items would be recognized on my PC, then move then back to the alternate drive for possible future use?
In theory this makes sense but I would like to hear of any of any possible caveats from others who may have tried something similar.

Comment: Thank you. That's a good chunk of real estate I can free up.

Answer (score 1):

An installation file can be invoked from any disk and (almost) any folder.

You may move the installation files anywhere you like and there is no need
to copy them back.